# How to Convert Char set in android?

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, unicode, localization

When using Facebook api I get these characters as a json response. I think these are Unicode characters. How can I convert them into normal characters ?

```
\u0dbb\u0d82\u0daf\u0dd2\u0d9a \u0da2\u0dba\u0d9a\u0dd9\u0dcf\u0da9\u0dd2
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml("\u0dbb\u0d82\u0daf\u0dd2\u0d9a \u0da2\u0dba\u0d9a\u0dd9\u0dcf\u0da9\u0dd2").toString();`