# Android get http response from PHP containing unicode character

Tags: php, android, json, unicode

I am writing an app using android, it is suppose to retrieve some Chinese characters from server, the server using php scripts, like here

```
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $link);
 $q= mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM ofPeers WHERE Address LIKE '$st' limit 0, 4");
 while($e = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    $output1=$output1.$e["Name"];

 print $output1;
```

the android using some code like

```
HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters,"UTF-8");        
request.setEntity(formEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I found I caught an exception when I executed the execute statement, like this Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of, Chinese Character. I think maybe it is caused by unicode, similar to this post
[How to Convert Char set in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518019/how-to-convert-char-set-in-android)

but, I currently have no idea on how to get rid of the error! Any suggestions!

Comment: Do the Chinese characters look correct in a web browser? If you can run fiddler can you snapshot the response in RAW format? I'm particularly interested to see if there any character encoder tags in the response header.

Comment: Yes, the Chinese characters looks correct in firefox, I have tested that point. I never use the fiddler before, I try to use it, and let you know the result!

Answer (score 0):

```
$output1=$output1.$e["Address"];
```

Would appear to be just concatenating all the results together into one string. That won't give you JSON output, so as you appear to be parsing the response as JSON you can expect a syntax error.

You probably want to drop all your addresses into an array and then use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert that into a JSON response that Android can read.

Also you have an SQL injection vulnerability. Please use `mysql_real_escape_string` over `$st` before including it in the query, or, better, use a parameterised query (available in `mysqli` and PDO). Use `mysql_set_charset` in preference to the explicit `SET CHARACTER SET` as otherwise `mysql_real_escape_string` will perform incorrectly in some corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did not use json in my php, actually, I just use string, I thought the reason should be caused by unicode! Also, thanks for your remind of my security problem in php snippets!